# how to extract a number string member from a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, casting

i want to extract number string values of a char array. Actually I want to extract numbers embeded in file names for some file management. For example if there is a file name as **file21** then i want the decimal number **21** from this file name.

How can i extract these values?

I tried the following but it results in an unexpected value. I think it is as a result of the implicit typecasting from the char to int while doing the arthimetic operation.

```
char * fname;
cout<<"enter file name";
cin>>fname;

int filenum=fname[4]%10+fname[5];
cout<<"file number is"<<filenum;
```

NOTE:
The filenamse are strictly in the format **fileXX**, **XX** being numbers between 01 and 99

Comment: If the string had something like "A3L5", would you want 35?

Comment: This code is wrong in many ways but try inputting to `std::string fname;` instead of to a `char*`, and take it from there.  What happens if user inputs 1 char only?  Poof.

Comment: @chris: the filename are strictly in the format **file22.tx**

Comment: @chris: the filename are strictly in the format **file22.tx**

Comment: Oh, wouldn't a `stringstream ss (file); ss >> someInt;` work then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subtract `'0'` to get the decimal value of a digit character:

```
int filenum=(fname[4]-'0')*10+(fname[5]-'0');
```

Better yet, you should use `atoi`:

```
int filenum = atoi(fname+4);
```

Comment: Why use `atoi` when there are C++ alternatives?

Comment: @chris C++ alternatives are somewhat more convoluted, even compared to the OP's idea of "parsing" the number manually. `atoi` is a [first class member](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) of C++ standard library, why not use it on something that's decidedly not *that* C++ - ish to begin with?

Comment: True, the question is vastly more C than C++. Never a bad time to get started though imo.

Comment: hah, then `scanf("file%d.txt", &filenum);` beats everything, hands down.

Comment: @Agent_L I wouldn't call it "hands down": anything that involves more typing cannot be hands down by the very definition of hands down :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight but it replaces cin, string splicing AND atoi. 
Hands down, by your definition : D

Comment: @Agent_L I think it replaces only the `atoi` bit - reading `fname`, from `cin` or otherwise, should still happen somewhere else, assuming `fname` is not a throw-away variable. Of course if `fname` is not used anywhere else, then there's no question about "hands down": one-line solutions always win!

Comment: @chris what C++ alternatives? atoi is in the library just for that, stringstream can do it as well, but atoi is faster (execution wise) and for what the op is doing, well suited for the task. So, what other c++ alternatives are you referring to? *opens standard's specification pdf*

Comment: `atoi` has no error checking availability. `strtol`, stringstreams, etc do.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting undefined behavior because you're never allocating memory for the `char*` you read into:

```
char * fname = new char[16];  //should be enough for your filename format
```

or better yet

```
char fname[16];
```

Also, what do you expect:

```
fname[4]%10+fname[5];
```

to do? Magically concatenate the numbers?

First, you convert the first char to an `int`, multiply it by `10`, convert the second char to an `int` and add to the first one. A simple google search for `char to int` would get you there.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i extract these values?

There are an infinite number of ways. One way is to use `std::istringstream`:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main () {
  std::string fname;
  std::cout << "Enter file name: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, fname);

  int filenum;
  std::istringstream stream(fname.substr(4,2));

  if(stream >> filenum)
    std::cout << "file number is " << filenum << "\n";
  else
    std::cout << "Merde\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int filenum;
  string fname;
  cout<<"enter file name";
  cin>>fname;

  string str2 = fname.substr(4,2);
  istringstream(str2) >> filenum;
  cout<<"file number is"<<filenum;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is that much defined, the simplest solution is scanf:

```
int main()
{
    int theNumber = 0;
    scanf("file%d.txt", &theNumber);
    printf("your number is %d", theNumber);
}
```

Check it out in action, reading from char* instead of stdio: http://codepad.org/JFqS70yI

scanf (and sscanf) also throws in checking for proper input format: returns number of fields read successfully. In this case if return value is any other than 1, the input was wrong.